# Are Metro style apps portable on iphone and ipad and also for web applications?

Tags: ios, html, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

What i wanted to know is if i develop a single metro style app using html5 and javascript can d same app be used for iphone and ipad as well?

Can anybody help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can create an app with pure JavaScript+HTML5+CSS3 which should work cross-platforms (to the degree of web standards support in browsers). You would need to package the app differently for different platforms or just host it like a website, but it should work. The problem is - usually when you develop Metro style apps for Windows 8 - you use WinJS APIs or general WinRT APIs to interface with the OS, which would not work cross-plaforms, so it really depends on how complicated your app is, how much effort you want to put in the development and is it really the right choice to have it look the same on all platforms. A Metro-style app could look a bit out of place on iOS or Android devices and vice-versa (although you could argue Metro style looks great everywhere and should be the easiest to port), while if you try to create something that works everywhere - you might end up with something as ugly as desktop Java apps were historically. Doing a shared cross-platform design might be counterproductive and countereffective.